# Historical Sequence

Tags: number-sequence, knowledge, sequence

What is the next number in the sequence?

10, 5, 9, 7, 6, 5, 7, 5, 8, ?

Hint 1:

> The numbers do not depend on each other.

Hint 2:

> The sequence is finite.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Next number is

> 5

because

> The $n$th number is the number of letters in the $n$th president's last name.
>  The next president is John Tyler. "Tyler" has five letters.

Title:

> The sequence depends on US history.

Hint 1:

> The presidents' names are independent of each other.

Hint 2:

> There is a finite number of presidents so far.

Comment: Correct, accepted!

Comment: Completely irrelevant, but utterly fascinating bit of trivia: It's now 2018, and [two people](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/how-two-of-president-john-tylers-grandsons-are-still-alive/) can still call the next number in the series their grandpa.